# How to know if my InputStream is working or has proper value

Tags: android, inputstream, android-bitmap

I'm using ImageView from Internal Storage. The flow is:

1) check if filename in Internal Storage already exists
2) if it does, use it as Bitmap in the ImageView
3) if not, download from URL, set as Bitmap to ImageView, and copy the Stream to a file in Internal Storage

Actual code is as

```
        try{
            InputStream fis = holder.mImageView.getContext().openFileInput("file.png");
            tempImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis));
            fileFound = true;
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
             try{                    
                FileOutputStream fos = holder.mImageView.getContext().openFileOutput("file.png",Context.MODE_APPEND);
                thumbPhotoRef.getStream(
                        new StreamDownloadTask.StreamProcessor() {
                            @Override
                            public void doInBackground(StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot,
                                                       InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                                int size;
                                tempImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
                                while ((size = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                                }
                                fos.close();
                                // Close the stream at the end of the Task
                                inputStream.close();
                            }
                        });
            }
            catch(IOException e){

            }
        }
```

tempImageView is a globally declared ImageView handler that is referencing to an ImageView in the layout

The logic in getStream method where Image Bitmap is assigned by:
tempImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));

this actually worked and Image is updated appropriately in the layout. Note that in this same method, the same input stream is being written to "fos" FileOutputStream variable pointing to "file.png".

No errors or anything including in debug, but somehow, the next time the file is opened, which was supposedly written to before already, failed to set the Bitmap of the ImageView. And I'm sure the file is now existent because the openFileInput does not go to file not found Exception anymore.

```
InputStream fis = holder.mImageView.getContext().openFileInput("file.png");
            tempImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis));
```

Any ideas what went wrong, or how do I get the value of variable fis in debug mode to see if it actually contained any Bitmap data that is understandable by setImageBitmap? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Just found out that InputStream is actually consumed once used.

My solution is to just read the InputStream again that was written to by the OutputStream earlier so that I'd get a copy:

```
                                OutputStream fos = holder.mImageView.getContext().openFileOutput(path,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                while ((size = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                                }
                                InputStream isCopy = tempImageView.getContext().openFileInput("file.png");
                                tempImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isCopy));
```